# why does annotation select event stop working?

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'm adding annotations (`SKAnnotation`) to a `SKMapView` and listening to the select event by implementing the `didSelectAnnotation` delegate method. The event works correctly at first but stops working when I navigate into another view controller and then navigate back to the map.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

1. Add an annotation to the map
2. Listen to the `didSelectAnnotation` event
3. Navigate to another view using `pushViewController:animated:` when the `didSelectAnnotation` listener is called
4. Navigate back to the map using `popViewControllerAnimated:`
5. Now the annotation `didSelectAnnotation` listener is never called again when tapping the annotation

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and was fixed with the 2.1.0 SDK update (available for download on http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download)